# Display WGYWAM to the front-end using Channel Form Field

Tags: wygwam, channel, forms

I created a form using channel fields and i'm trying to figure how to allow the WYGWAM features to display on the front-end so, the end-user can do some basic text formatting.

```
            {exp:channel:form channel="careers"
                form:role="form"
                form:data-toggle="validator"
                include_jquery="yes"
                datepicker="no"
                id="careers"
                return="careers/thank-you"
                logged_out_member_id="2797"
                preserve_checkboxes="yes"
                status="pending"
                dynamic_title="[careers_job_title]"
                rules:careers_job_title="required"
            }
```

This is the channel field that I'm trying to add the WYGWAM to:

```
<div class="form-group"> 
  <label for="careers_job_description">Job Description</label> 
  <textarea class="form-control" rows="5"></textarea> 
</div>
```

Comment: This is the channel field that I'm trying to add the WYGWAM to
<div class="form-group">
<label for="**careers_job_description**">Job Description</label>
<textarea class="form-control" rows="5"></textarea>
</div>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a guess you've not specified your WYGWAM field name you've created for the channel. [Details here](https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/add-ons/channel/channel_form/#other-channel-fields).

```
<div class="form-group"> 
  <label for="careers_job_description">Job Description</label> 
  <textarea class="form-control" name="{field:wygwam_field_name}" rows="5"></textarea> 
</div>
```

Not sure if you can just use `{my_field_name}` without the `field:` prefix.

Tag Pair:

```
{my_field_name}{/my_field_name}
```

Alternative:

```
{custom_fields}
    {if textarea}
    <textarea id="{field_name}" name="{field_name}" dir="{text_direction}" rows="{rows}">
        {field_data}
    </textarea>
    {/if}
{/custom_fields}
```

Comment: Thank you Peter! With your input I was able to get it working. 

My code looked like this:
<div class="form-group">
<label for="careers_job_description">Job Description</label>
{field:careers_job_description}
</div>